# How to get the indexPath of a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

Right now I have a longPressGesture on my collection view cell.

```
@IBAction func longGesture(sender: AnyObject) {


    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        let location = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
        println(location)
        let index = whoCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location)
        println(index)

    }

}
```

This is my code for the longPressGesture. I am getting good results on my location but for anything other then the last cell in the collectionView, I get nil for the index. On the last cell the index is 0.

I also tried replacing sender.view with self.view but that gives me weird results also. 60% of the long gestures I have return nil when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let location = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
```

the locationInView will need to be the collectionview, so that it can calculate using the cells frame.

Try

```
let location = sender.locationInView(whoCollectionView.view)
```

Comment: That should be whoCollectionView, not whoCollectionView.view